# Is there any event to identify that a page has been terminated in c#?

Tags: c#, events, session

Is there any event to identify that a page has been terminated in c#? I have a scenario where i need certain session variables to get removed when i navigate from page 'A' to any other page. Im not using response.redirect() to navigate to another page. So how will i know when i exit A?

Comment: Why don't you put the values in `viewstate` itself so they are cleaned automatically?

Comment: My scenario demands the values to be kept in session. Its shared across some pages. But after I open page A they are no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the onbeforeunload event: It is fired just before the page is unloaded

Follow this link

https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you need some specific action getting from page A to page B. you should think about making a call to the server , do your stuff and then redirect to the page B.

otherwise you might work on the link client side, and make some JQuery call to the server while redirecting, so that receiving the call, the server is doing your stuff.

If you are looking for some general exit from a page, you are entering a world of pain.

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact way to handle unload event of the page.
But you can writer some javascript as mentioned in above answer..

Thanks